# How can I use phaser with angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, game-engine, phaser-framework

I need to make a game for a website that works with angular 4 (or at least 2).

I don't know what is the best approach, as I'm used to making games with c++ and only have some experience with phaser and basic html, css and javascritp. I've started reading the angular documentation and I'm beginning to be familiar with the framework. I'm liking typescript more than javascript.

Is it possible to use phaser with angular 4? (preferably with typescript)

If so, is it a good idea or is there a better aproach? html canvas maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Phaser` takes control of a canvas, `Angular4/5` can still manages the routes or any other logistic workflow logic

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/building-games-with-angular.html

This article is for angular1, but yes, you can use Angular4/5 as well. You can either do a wrapper for `Phaser` or just use new `Phaser` object.

Comment: The source is not longer available